# SQL- creating a user-defined function in SSMS

Tags: sql, function, ssms

I need help writing a query- I need to create a function where if I input a Code number, it will return the PACEESRD info for a specific year. I have a table for 2018 and a table for 2019, with the same column names.
Here is a piece of the table...

```
+--------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+--------+
| Code   | Description   | PACEESRD | V22 | V23 |   Rx   |
+--------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+--------+
| A0103  | pneumonia     |    113   | 113 | 113 |   Null |
| A0104  | sepsis        |    40    | 40  |  40 |   Null |
| A0105  | plague        |    40    | 40  |  40 |   Yes  | 
| A021   | arthritis     |    38    | 38  |  38 |   No   |
| A207   | colitis       |   41     | 41  |  41 |  Null  |
+--------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Good luck. If you have a question, be sure to ask SO.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a user-defined function that takes 2 parameters: Year and Code. The function then returns the PACEESRD value from the table corresponding to the Year parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetPACEESRD
(
    @Year int,
    @Code nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar int;
    IF (@Year = 2018)
        SELECT @ResultVar = PACEESRD FROM Table2018 WHERE Code = @Code;
    ELSE
    IF (@Year = 2019)
        SELECT @ResultVar = PACEESRD FROM Table2019 WHERE Code = @Code;
    RETURN @ResultVar;
END
```

You can test the function like this:

```
select dbo.GetPACEESRD(2018, 'A0103');
```

Please modify the data types so that they match the data types of your tables.
The function assumes that the Code values are unique within each table. If they are not unique the function will fail and must be modified.